# Get the ID on an LI on a mouse.enter event in Dojo

Tags: dojo, mouseover

How do I get, in Dojo, the ID of a node on mouse.enter? I am trying to get the ID of an LI during a rollover, both UL and LI have IDs. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `dojo/on` module, but even easier is using the `dojo/query` module since it allows you to directly add event handlers.

An example:

```js
query("ul#myList li").on(mouse.leave, function(evt) {
    console.log(evt.target.id);
});
```

I also made an example [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g00glen00b/8Hjj2/).

Comment: Wow, thank you. You are awesome! Thank you for the written example also. It is exactly what I was looking for. I just started studying Dojo and I am loving it.